# How do I map from List<string> to List<string> in AutoMapper C#?

Tags: c#, list, automapper

I'll just cut to the chase.
I have a model file where I have a list of strings, it looks like this:

```
public class Source
{
    public List<string> myList { get; set; }
}
```

And the class I want to map it to looks like this:

```
public class Destination
{
    public List<string> myList { get; set; }
}
```

I'm pretty new to AutoMapper and so I don't know how I am supposed to map this. I get an error saying that "Source.myList" cannot be mapped because it is a list of strings and apparently AutoMapper doesn't support that because it's not a primitive or whatever.

How do I fix this?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish exactly? There are much easier ways to copy a list from one to another if that is the goal.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>());
var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
var source = new Source() { myList = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" } };
var dest = mapper.Map<Destination>(source);
Debug.Assert(dest.myList.Count == 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the mapping documentation for classes and collections [here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection).

Also, good examples can be found in [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/61629/AutoMapper) post.